# Access variable of stdClass Object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, stdclass

I am using Laravel with a select statement to select the row with the highest id like this:

```
$user_id = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('SELECT MAX(id) FROM users')[0];
```

This returns an array with an object that looks like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [MAX(id)] => 11 ) 1
```

I have tried `$object->MAX(id)` and `$object['MAX(id)']` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php Maybe this function can help you.

Comment: `$object->{'MAX(id)'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic attributes with usually not allowed characters can be accessed using curly brackets like this:

```
$object->{"MAX(id)"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using the RAW queries when you can utilise the power of Eloquent. You can do this

```
User::max('id')
```

This code will return the maximum value of 'id' column in 'users' table. Given that you have set up your model `User`. You can [read more](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#aggregates) about Eloquent max at given docs link.